# Char array pointer in C

Tags: c

I want to run this code but i can not. i have yet started to learn pointer in C. I am trying to get the addresses of letters. Problem is `printf("in adress: %p\n",p[i])`;` Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    char letter;
    int c=0;
    int i;
    char pattern[7];
    char *p;
    printf("Enter a letter: ");
    scanf("%c",&letter);
    printf("Enter a pattern: ");
    scanf("%s",pattern);
    p=pattern;
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
    {
        if(letter==pattern[i])
        {
            c++;
            printf("Letter < %c > is found in pattern %s\n",letter,pattern);
            printf("in adress: %p\n",p[i]);
            printf("index:%d\n",i);
        }

    }
    if(c==0)
        printf("The pattern does not include any letter");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `p[i]` is not the address of the i'th element of p - it's the *value*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code has some potential problem that can easily happen

```
scanf("%s",&pattern);
```

you can make it a little bit safer like this

```
scanf("%6s",&pattern);
```

it's a `6` because you need one extra byte `'\0'` at the end of the string, which takes us to the next problem

```
for(i=0;i<7;i++)
```

here you are assuming that all bytes are non-`nul` which would be ok except that you are reading a string with `scanf()` and unless you create the array one byte bigger than the number of characters you want to store in it, `scanf()` will overflow the array i.e. write a byte beyond it's bounds.

Adding the `"%6s"` length specifier to the format string solves this, but you can only store `6` non-`nul` bytes in the array, and for the other problem

```
for (i = 0 ; pattern[i] != '\0' ; i++)
```

would be better, because you don't need to know the length of the string in advance and you don't risk reading past the end of the array.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char  letter;
    char  c;
    int   i; 
    char  pattern[7];
    printf("Enter a letter: ");
    if (scanf(" %c",&letter) != 1)
     {
        printf("error: invalid input.\n");
        return -1;
     }
    printf("Enter a pattern: ");
    if (fgets(pattern, sizeof(pattern), stdin) == NULL)
     {
        printf("error: end of file.\n");
        return -1;
     }
    for (i = 0 ; pattern[i] != 0 ; ++i)
    {
        if (letter == pattern[i])
        {
            c++;
            printf("Letter < %c > is found in pattern %s\n", letter, pattern);
            printf("in adress: %p\n", pattern + i);
            printf("index    :%d\n", i);
        }

    }
    if (c == 0)
        printf("The pattern does not include any letter");
    return 0;
}
```

You also was printg the address wrong, because in `pointer[i]` the subscript operator dereferences the pointer, it's equivalent to `*(poitner + i)`.

Comment: q1.c: In function ‘main’:
q1.c:12:2: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[7]’ [-Wformat=]
  scanf("%6s",&pattern);
  ^
q1.c:20:4: warning: format ‘%p’ expects argument of type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
    printf("in adress: %p\n",p[i]);
I have these mistakes now

Comment: The problem is `&pattern`, it's good that you are using warnings, a good way to learn is to try and interpret the warnings and errors and think about why it couldn't work the way you wrote it. Use `fgets()` instead, as the code I posted